# Keep audio and video in sync HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have HTML5 video and audio elements that I'm needing to keep in sync with each other. Eg. if the video buffers then the audio would pause until the video is ready again.

Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: For perfect synchronization, not possible, sorry. If you're content with a solution that will get you anywhere from perfect sync to off-by-1-second, you'll need a combination of [the AV DOM events and methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to listen on both media elements for various [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) and handle them as appropriate.

If you notice one stop playing, for example, you can pause the other, set its current playback position to match the paused one, and then play once you notice it continue.

I would expect this to be fiddly and imprecise, but I can't think of a better way than this.

I'd begin by writing some code to listen for all events which look useful on each element and log them out when they happen, and then I'd observe to get a feel for what I need to respond to. Then lots and lots of testing with bandwidth limiting etc via browser dev tools.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad technique sorry to say .you can actually some other way by using some video editor tool like filmora to make audio and video in one video.it means attach audio to the video according to your desire .
hope you get the best 
best of luck